# Adding Properties to WCF DataContract

Tags: vb.net, wcf, serialization

I've added a service reference to my WCF webservice which generated all of my datacontract objects.  I'm using BasicHttpBinding.  Using a partial class, I've made one of these objects inherit from another class that adds some properties to it.  Now it throws an error when making a call to the service:

> Test method CP.Exg2010.Tests.UnitTest1.TestWCF threw exception: 
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The
>   formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:
>   There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:RunResult. The InnerException message was 'Error
>   in line 1 position 283. 'Element' 'CommandResult' from namespace
>   'uri://mycomp.corp/line/exg2010' is not expected. Expecting element
>   '_EngineTracingData'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
>   ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in
>   line 1 position 283. 'Element' 'CommandResult' from namespace
>   'uri://mycomp.corp/line/exg2010' is not expected. Expecting element
>   '_EngineTracingData'.

`CommandResult` is a property that is part of the WSDL. `_EngineTracingData` is the private field used by a property in a base class.

```
<XmlIgnore()> <SoapIgnore()> <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore()> _
Private _EngineTracingData As String = String.Empty
<XmlIgnore()> <SoapIgnore()> <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore()>
Public Property EngineTracingData As String Implements Interfaces.ICPMasterBaseInfo.EngineTracingData
    Get
        Return Me._EngineTracingData
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me._EngineTracingData = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I read something about the deserialization happening in alphabetic order, which would explain why `_EngineTracingData` is first.  But, that field/property shouldn't even be used in deserialization!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found it!

Adding

<NonSerialized()>

to the private fields in the base class fixed my issue!